# I can't write some text value on a canvas in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, canvasjs

I'm programming a JSON converter API and I use canvas to draw some diagrams.
In one some of my text value that labels elements are not written on the canvas, but I can read it with a console.log. I don't know what is the problem and how to fix it. Hope it will be easy to fix, here is the code...

```
var nodename = json.kmap.elements.nodes[nodeIndex].data.name;
console.log(nodename);
ctx.font = "35px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
if (nodename.length > 25){
    var strcut = nodename.indexOf(" ", 25);
    if (strcut != -1){
        var nodename1 = nodename.slice(0, strcut);
        var nodename2 = nodename.slice(strcut, nodename.length);
        ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#444444';
        ctx.fillRect(xpos - ctx.measureText(nodename1).width / 2, ypos - (45 * multip) - 30,ctx.measureText(nodename1).width, 35);
        ctx.fillRect(xpos - ctx.measureText(nodename2).width / 2, ypos - (30 * multip) - 30,ctx.measureText(nodename2).width, 35);
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#555555';
        ctx.fillText(nodename1, xpos , ypos - (45 * multip));
        ctx.fillText(nodename2, xpos , ypos - (30 * multip));
    }
} else {
    ctx.globalAlpha = alpha;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#444444';
    ctx.fillRect(xpos - ctx.measureText(nodename).width / 2, ypos - (30 * multip) - 30,ctx.measureText(nodename).width, 35);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#555555';
    ctx.fillText(nodename, xpos, ypos - (30 * multip));
}
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(xpos, ypos, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#a3d039';
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Which labels are not written? Have you checked the calculated coordinates for the case they'd cause the text to be positioned outside of the canvas?

Comment: Extending on @Teemu comment, try hardcoding the coordinates to center of the canvas... you are also doing something with global alpha make sure that is not making it disappear

Comment: This code works for almost every node exept for some random points (it's in a foreach loop and i have over 60 points with text) and hardcoding the coordinate didn't works. I reset the alpha each time i want somthing clean (i also tried to set my alpha variable to 1 and it didn't worked)